# Calculating SUM with UPDATE in visual studio using access

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, sql-update, sum, insert-update

I have three tables. ADDinv, REMinv, and CURRENTinv.

"ADDinv" - CASNumber, ChemicalName, DateIn, Measurment, Volume, OrderNumber.
"REMinv" - CASNumber, ChemicalName, DateOut, Measurment, Volume, OrderNumber.
"CURRENTinv" - CASNumber, ChemicalName, LastDateIn, LastDateOut, Measurment, Volume.

I have code to enter data  to the ADDinv and  REMinv table.

The CURRENTinv table is already populated with all of the "CASNumber and ChemicalName".
What I am looking to do is, where those values are consistent with data entered in "ADDinv" I want to use a SUM calculation to update the "Volume" column in the "CURRENTinv" table. And also update the column with the "LastDateIn" in the "CURRENTinv" with the "DateIn" from the "ADDinv"

To update this data to the CURRENTinv Table, I have came up with this and get this error "Additional information: Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."

```
            'update current inv table

          Dim sum = "CURRENTinventory(volume)" + VolumeTextBox.Text

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE CURRENTinventory " & _
                "SET LastDateIn=" & Me.DateTimePicker.Text & _
                ", Volume='" = sum & _
                "WHERE Chemicalname=" & Me.ChemicalNameComboBox.Text

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I thought I covered that in the question I asked. I will try and make it clearer.

Comment: Any help would be great!

Comment: still looking for some help..